# Extract words from string in java by its beginning and its length

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract a part of a text from a string knowing the beginning of the word and its length.

For example, I have the following string:

```
"snfsdb bvyvujmnhellonmnfu"
```

My rule is:

```
The word start by "hel" and has a length of 5.
```

It should return

```
"hello"
```

What would be the best way to achieve that?

Comment: `indexOf` and `substring`

Comment: Thanks for sharing your requirements. Now we would gladly hear your question, see your attempts to solve solve it and how was it not working as you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/hel\w{2}/` should do the trick. That matches the literal "hel" followed by any 2 word characters, which are defined as the character class [a-zA-Z_0-9]

Comment: The `/`s are unneeded in Java's regexes. Just `hel\w\w` would work.

Comment: Wow, an accepted, upvoted, wrong answer. There's nothing in the OP's requirements that says "hel" must be followed by two word characters, only "hel" and a length of 5. `indexOf` and `substring` is the way to solve this, regexes, as usual, are overkill at best.

Comment: @DavidConrad The first line of the OP's question says that he is extracting a WORD, hence the use of WORD characters. I even explicitly told him what the `\w{2}` would match in case there was a misunderstanding. It does what he wants and correctly answered his question. You can sleep easy tonight, in this particular case the person on the internet that is wrong is you.

Comment: Fair enough, but I still think a regex is overkill here.